# Working with vector representation of individual feature

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering, importance

Generally, training data is of shape $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ data where $n$ is the number of samples and $m$ is the number of features. The training data can be represented in a table such as

| feat1 | feat2 | ... | feat n | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Val1 | Val2 | ... | Val n | label1 |
| Val1 | Val2 | ... | Val n | label2 |

In this case, as you can see each feature is represented by a single value.

Now, I have a dataset where each feature is represented with a vector instead of a value. For example,

| feat1 | feat2 | ... | feat n | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Vec 1] | [Vec 2] | ... | [Vec n] | label1 |
| [Vec 1] | [Vec 2] | ... | [Vec n] | label2 |

Each vector is the same size. And the values within the vector are all numbers are $\ge 0$.

Do I just convert my training data as following

| feat1 val1 | feat1 val2 | ... | feat_n val1 | feat_n val2 | ... | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Val11 | Val12 | ... | Valn1 | Valn2 | ... | label1 |
| Val11 | Val12 | ... | Valn1 | Valn2 | ... | label2 |

This does kinda solve the issue, but it seems like a whacky solution. Also, if I split the feature from a vector representation to a list of scalar representation and treat each of them as individual features, that kinda lose the true representation of the feature in the first place.

I am assuming we can use the convolutional neural network, however, if the number of training data is small (i.e. 100s), a neural network might not be the best option. Also, If the objective is the find the important features eventually, what feature selection/ML method might work?

Comment: When you convert your data from scalar values (i.e., $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$) to vector values, is the shape $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m \times c}$? If so, you can use a CNN.

Comment: The number of features and the number of samples are not enough (i.e. 100s). Should CNN still be applicable?

Comment: it may be but probably not. You may be better off using another ML algorithm like an SVM or XGBoost if it's tabular.

Answer (score 1):

I need more description to answer more accurately. My answer is based on my understanding of your question. I hope it helps you.

In your problem, you can not use conventional neural networks because your data are not a matrix. You have some features and you normalize the features. Then, you can use MLP (a type of neural network).
if you want to change features to vectors, it depends on the data type of values for each feature. It depends on many things for converting values to vectors. If values are numbers, you just need to keep values in the same range like [0,1]. If data are True/False, just convert them to 0 and 1. The machine learning algorithms can find hidden info among features and solve your problem (in most cases). If the feature values are not the same (different data types), you must use different methods. We have different encodings for string or categorical data and conversion to numerical values/vectors. Some encodings are one-hot, target, label, and binary encodings.

If the data is small, you can use some traditional ML methods like SVM, XGBoost, Decision Trees and so on. This is based on my experience. There might be other methods and I am not aware of them. So do more research.